# Conguring Hound.ci to work with BEM

Tags: css, bem

I am using **[Hound CI](https://houndci.com/)** as my code style cop, and **[BEM](http://getbem.com/introduction/)** for my css naming, and Hound doesn't like BEM. How do you configure Hound to avoid commenting on BEM class names?

Comment: Could tell us what you've got setup with Hound and BEM thus far so we know what point you're at with it?

Answer (score 0):

Hound uses [SCSS-lint](https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint) for SCSS linting rules. To get Hound to account for BEM, we need to set the linter's [selectorFormat](https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint/blob/dc8b59b46964db1ab44bd8a3385dbf6d541602f9/lib/scss_lint/linter/README.md#selectorformat) convention to `hyphenated_BEM`. Here's one way to do so:

Hound looks for a `.hound.yml` file for your initial configuration. So, lets start by telling Hound to use a specific SCSS linter config file:

```
#.houndl.yml

scss:
  config_file: .scss-linter-config.yml
```

Then we can set up our custom config in our SCSS linter file:

```
#.scss-linter-config.yml

linters:
  SelectorFormat:
    enabled: true
    convention: hyphenated_BEM
```

We should now get Hound comments that apply to BEM!